# get mac addresses of wireless adapters in c++ on WinXP and above

Tags: c++, windows, wireless, iphelper

I would like to have the above.
I found the IP Helper API, and it works. Only problem is that on systems older than Vista I can not identify whether the adapter is wireless or a regular Ethernet.
I need to support WinXP and Server 2003 as well.

Here is the relevant quote from the documentation([IP Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> An IEEE 802.11 wireless network interface.
>   Note  This adapter type is returned on Windows Vista and later. On Windows Server 2003 and >Windows XP , an IEEE 802.11 wireless network interface returns an adapter type of >MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET.

**So what is a good way to identify wireless adapters and get their MAC addresses on WinXP/Server2003 and later?**

Comment: Windows XP pre SP1? or is SP2-3 valid targets?

Answer (score 0):

[GetAdapterAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a part of the windows api, and should provide you with both information about mac addresses and NIC type.

The call return a structure pointing to a linked list of adapters.

Make sure that you do not hard code the size of the structure to maintain portability between windows versions, because the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` structure have changed size between versions.

**Edit:**

This obviously only give you the mac address, since it only reports correct type after Vista

But,
[GetIfTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a `MIB_IFTABLE` structure, from this you can read a `MIB_IFROW` which has a dwType, which might be of the type IF_TYPE_IEEE80211 or not. This has no notes that this is spesific for Vista and should be valid for XP unless MS messed up their documentation.

Both of these should have a physical address, so you should be able to match these two entries to identify one single card.

Comment: Same problem with this function, I can't know whether it's a wireless or regular adapter.
From the docs: An IEEE 802.11 wireless network interface.
On Windows Vista and later, wireless network cards are reported as IF_TYPE_IEEE80211. On earlier versions of Windows, wireless network cards are reported as IF_TYPE_ETHERNET_CSMACD.
On Windows XP with SP3 and on Windows XP with SP2 x86 with the Wireless LAN API for Windows XP with SP2 installed, the WlanEnumInterfaces function can be used to enumerate wireless interfaces on the local computer.

Comment: @michaelr524 I digged a litter deeper, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for digging :)
I will have to test your assumption before I can accept your answer.

Comment: Well, I tested it and all the wireless adapters come out as Ethernet. Too bad.

Comment: Ok, ill leave my answer standing for a while. So anyone can know what doesn't work for you. I'll keep looking though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to support XP from scratch, this is before the Native Wifi API was introduced to XP (SP 2 & 3 support the Native Wifi API).

I think there still might be an opportunity through [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You might be able to create a [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28VS.85%29.aspx) (A deprecated WMI class) In this class you should be able to extract `AdapterTypeID` which tells if it is a wireless device or not and `MACAddress` which gives you the MAC address.

So I think you choice is to either support Windows XP SP 2 and up or have to integrate with WMI and a deprecated class. Looks like there are camels to swallow in any case.

Comment: tried WMI on Windows 7, wifi adapter was reported as Ethernet 802.3 so i guess it doesn't work. here is the script i've used to test it:

`strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter")

For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objItem.Description
    Wscript.Echo "MACAddress: " & objItem.MACAddress
    Wscript.Echo "AdapterType: " & objItem.AdapterType
Next`